# Casting UUID Column in Postgre with pg-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, uuid, pg-promise

I'm trying update data using **ColumnSet()** in **pg-promise**, but always getting
`error: column "id_urutan" is of type uuid but expression is of type text`.

Yes, I know my `id_urutan` is UUID, but I don't know how to casting `the expression` to UUID.
And when I trying to cast using this code `[{name :'id_urutan',cnd:true, cast:'uuid'},` it get error `cannot cast id_urutan to uuid`

this is my last code for **ColumSet**

```
const cs = new dbconfig.pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([{name :'id_urutan',cnd:true, cast:'text'}, 'nomor_ujian_mahasiswa', 'urutan', 'id_station', 'id_tran_sesi_ujian_station'], {table: 'urutan_ujian_mahasiswa'});
```

thank you.

Comment: Exactly what `the expression` is?

Comment: it's text[], so I cast it to text

Comment: What is in `text[]`?

Comment: it's 'id_urutan' expression type

Comment: `const cs = new dbconfig.pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['?id_urutan']);` if I set the expression 'id_urutan' like this, it will be read as a `text[]` type

Comment: it's solved, thanks

Comment: That's probably because you incorrectly specified `cast:'text'` instead of `cast:'uuid'`